# How to remove catid and itemid from an url in joomla?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

I have link like this

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1885&catid=113&Itemid=435
```

how to remove the catid and itemid. these links are retrieving from google search results. So if i remove the catid and itemid and redirect to the link  index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1885

Comment: The best place to look for this kind of help is [Always in the manual](https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs)

Comment: Enable SEF (search engine friendly URL) in the configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *.htaccess* to strip the parameters. Something like this might work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)&amp;catid=[0-9a-z]+&amp;(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1&amp;%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)&amp;Itemid=[0-9a-z]+$|^Itemid=[0-9a-z]+&amp;?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1 [R=301,L]
```

---

Source: http://forums.westhost.com/showthread.php?t=8010&p=26446&viewfull=1#post26446

Answer (score 1):

enable joomla sef url to remove ids

Answer (score 0):

on the backend of your jooomla installation you can choose 'System'->'global configuration' in order to open the configuration page.
On that page you **enable the 'search engine friendly URLs**, like so:

[image]